# How can I play music represented as chords in a csv file with Python?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from tensorflow import keras

def load_chorales(filepaths):
    return [pd.read_csv(filepath).values.tolist() for filepath in filepaths]

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/raw/master/datasets/jsb_chorales/"
FILENAME = "jsb_chorales.tgz"
filepath = keras.utils.get_file(FILENAME,
                                DOWNLOAD_ROOT + FILENAME,
                                cache_subdir="datasets/jsb_chorales",
                                extract=True)


jsb_chorales_dir = Path(filepath).parent
train_files = sorted(jsb_chorales_dir.glob("train/chorale_*.csv"))
valid_files = sorted(jsb_chorales_dir.glob("valid/chorale_*.csv"))
test_files = sorted(jsb_chorales_dir.glob("test/chorale_*.csv"))

train_chorales = load_chorales(train_files)
valid_chorales = load_chorales(valid_files)
test_chorales = load_chorales(test_files)
```

The code downloads the Bach chorales dataset and unzips it. It is composed of 382 chorales composed by Johann Sebastian Bach. Each chorale is 100 to 640 time steps long, and each time step contains 4 integers, where each integer corresponds to a note's index on a piano (except for the value 0, which means that no note is played). This is an example of how a chorale (from the training set) might look like:

```
print(train_chorales[0])
[[74, 70, 65, 58],
 [74, 70, 65, 58],
 [74, 70, 65, 58],
 [74, 70, 65, 58],
 [75, 70, 58, 55],
...
 [70, 65, 62, 46],
 [70, 65, 62, 46],
 [70, 65, 62, 46]]
```

It is composed of 192 time steps (or chords, or 192 lists of 4 values. In other words, the above print statement would print 192 rows of lists of 4 integers).

In the dataset, notes range from 36 (C1 = C on octave 1) to 81 (A5 = A on octave 5), plus 0 for silence.

My question is the following: How can I play these chorales in Python? As in, I want to listen to them, how they sound. The extracted files are separated in 3 directories: `train`, `valid`, and `test`. The files in these directories are `.csv` files with 4 columns each (`note0`, `note1`, `note2`, and `note3`), one column for every possible pressed piano key in each chord of the chorale. How can I turn these lists of numbers into something that I can listen to? I've never done this before, so I have no idea how to tackle this. I hope I made clear what I want to do: I want to turn these chorales from the 3 files `train`, `valid`, and `test` into real sound in python, in other words turn these numbers into the actual music composed by Bach.

Comment: If you can convert the data into MIDI files, then there are modules available that can play those.

Comment: @martineau Ok, but how can I convert the data to MIDI files?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there are other third-party modules for that, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The github user Ageron you download the processed Bach chorales from has his own synthesizer that he uses to generate audio frequencies to hear the music.

```
from IPython.display import Audio

def notes_to_frequencies(notes):
    # Frequency doubles when you go up one octave; there are 12 semi-tones
    # per octave; Note A on octave 4 is 440 Hz, and it is note number 69.
    return 2 ** ((np.array(notes) - 69) / 12) * 440

def frequencies_to_samples(frequencies, tempo, sample_rate):
    note_duration = 60 / tempo # the tempo is measured in beats per minutes
    # To reduce click sound at every beat, we round the frequencies to try to
    # get the samples close to zero at the end of each note.
    frequencies = np.round(note_duration * frequencies) / note_duration
    n_samples = int(note_duration * sample_rate)
    time = np.linspace(0, note_duration, n_samples)
    sine_waves = np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequencies.reshape(-1, 1) * time)
    # Removing all notes with frequencies ≤ 9 Hz (includes note 0 = silence)
    sine_waves *= (frequencies > 9.).reshape(-1, 1)
    return sine_waves.reshape(-1)

def chords_to_samples(chords, tempo, sample_rate):
    freqs = notes_to_frequencies(chords)
    freqs = np.r_[freqs, freqs[-1:]] # make last note a bit longer
    merged = np.mean([frequencies_to_samples(melody, tempo, sample_rate)
                     for melody in freqs.T], axis=0)
    n_fade_out_samples = sample_rate * 60 // tempo # fade out last note
    fade_out = np.linspace(1., 0., n_fade_out_samples)**2
    merged[-n_fade_out_samples:] *= fade_out
    return merged

def play_chords(chords, tempo=160, amplitude=0.1, sample_rate=44100, filepath=None):
    samples = amplitude * chords_to_samples(chords, tempo, sample_rate)
    if filepath:
        from scipy.io import wavfile
        samples = (2**15 * samples).astype(np.int16)
        wavfile.write(filepath, sample_rate, samples)
        return display(Audio(filepath))
    else:
        return display(Audio(samples, rate=sample_rate))

play_chords(train_chorales[0])
```

Source: https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/15_processing_sequences_using_rnns_and_cnns.ipynb and repo source https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2

Run the first setup cell, then go to section 10, to see the audio cell in action.